# Issue in saving log data into file using typescript-logging in Angular11

Tags: angular, typescript, file, logging, error-logging

Does anyone have any idea about how to log the info/debug/error messages into a file ( example app.log or error.log) using typescript-logging for angular.
Or is there any better way to log the debug/info/errors into a file in Angular 11.
I am currently referring to this example but unable to find the way to log into a file.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-logging

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Angular app run on browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc). Hence it's limited by API of browser. Currently, i don't think browser have any API that allow app to write to file system (well you can read file but write to file is not possible).

So you have 2 options:

1. Log to console of browser
2. Send your logs to your BE server (using REST or whatever) then your BE will save it to is file system

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but I could see in below link that using log4js there is an option to append to a file but log4js has a challenge to work with angular applications, so I was exploring if we can do the same with typescript-logging. 
                          https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js